# Need help in google sheet - script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the logger values into a dedicated tab(history) in the same spreadsheet with a date and time stamp,
I am getting values in the logger just need to arrange them and copy them into a dedicated tab(history).
its gonna have 2 trigers per day and every day a new column in the new dedicated tab(history).
thank.

```js
// custom menu function
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('History')
      .addItem('save','saveData')
      .addToUi();
}

// function to save data
function saveData() {
  // starts with active sheet for data entry
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Moshiko");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("History");

  // collects values in data entry row
  var total = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!O11:O34").getValues();
  var daily = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!R11:R34").getValues();
  var portfolio = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!L11:L34").getValues();
  var lastportfolio = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!Q11:Q34").getValues();
  var curentstock = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!K11:K33").getValues();
  var laststock = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!P11:P33").getValues();  
  var buystock = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!I11:I33").getValues()
  var all = [[total,daily,portfolio,lastportfolio,curentstock,laststock,buystock,]];
 
  Logger.log(all);
```

Comment: @mshiko yazdi - Kindly include what data should look like in the History tab.

Comment: https://imgur.com/KJsUyG6
this is the logger results 
https://imgur.com/CoNIMYL
this is how i want it to be look like

Comment: anyone can help plz?

Answer (score 0):

### Issues:

1. The return of `.getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. Appending `[[]]`
   will make it 4 dimensional array. `.setValues()` can only take 2
   dimensional array.
2. The data collected is in row data. Each row represent sub-array in our 2d array.

   Row data example: `[[a][b][c][d]]`

*This is what it looks like in sheets:*

[image]

### Solution:

1. Merge the collected row data using concat(). This will make `[[a][b][c][d]]` into `[a,b,c,d]`.
2. Since the structure of the concatenated data is now in single row format, we can transpose it to make it column data.

**Example Data:**

[image: Example]

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  // starts with active sheet for data entry
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Moshiko");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("History");


  // collects values in data entry row
  var total = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!O11:O34").getValues();
  var daily = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!R11:R34").getValues();
  var portfolio = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!L11:L34").getValues();
  var lastportfolio = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!Q11:Q34").getValues();
  var curentstock = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!K11:K33").getValues();
  var laststock = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!P11:P33").getValues();  
  var buystock = sheet.getRange("Moshiko!I11:I33").getValues();

  var columns = [["Total", "Daily", "portfolio", "lastportfolio", "currentstock", "laststock", "buystock"]]
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var dateStamp = [["Date stamp", date]]
  
  //concat each 2d array to make 1d array and enclose the 1d arrays with '[]'  to make it 2d. 
  var arr = [[].concat(...total),[].concat(...daily),[].concat(...portfolio),[].concat(...lastportfolio),[].concat(...curentstock),
            [].concat(...laststock),[].concat(...buystock)];

  //set dateStamp
  sheet2.getRange("A1:B1").setValues(dateStamp);
  //set columns
  sheet2.getRange("A2:G2").setValues(columns);
  //set values
  Logger.log(arr)

  var transposed_arr = transpose(arr);
  Logger.log(transposed_arr.length);
  Logger.log(transposed_arr[0].length);
  sheet2.getRange(3, 1, transposed_arr.length, transposed_arr[0].length).setValues(transposed_arr);
}

function transpose(matrix) {
  return matrix[0].map((col, i) => matrix.map(row => row[i]));
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

### Reference:

[Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

[setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

[getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Ty so much! i have a question tho , in this lines i didnt understand what i need to fill, if i need to fill.?

//concat each 2d array to make 1d array and enclose the 1d arrays with '[]' to make it 2d. var arr = [[].concat(...total),[].concat(...daily),[].concat(...portfolio),[].concat(...lastportfolio),[].concat(...curentstock), [].concat(...laststock),[].concat(...buystock)];

once again , thanks alot! you are a life saver

Comment: one more thing, when i use the script its deleting the the data and rewrite it , if i want the every time i run the (which will be twice a day) it will write the date in the next empty columns and not to rewrite on the only data, how can i do this?

Comment: @moshiko yazdi - No need to fill anything. I used spread to iterate the elements of the array instead of using loop. [Javascript Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: sheet2.insertColumnsBefore(1,8)
fix the problem XD
Thank you so much for the help ! its working great now